# Audio into HTML file

Tags: html

I need help putting a YouTube song into an html format. Basically I want to hear music in the background of my website but I don't want to see the actual video.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>MelonRP loading screen</title>

    <style type="text/css">       
        body {
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        background-color:#000000
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <object style="height:0px; width:0px;">
        <embed src="" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAcess="always" width="0" height="0">
    </object>

    <img src="MelonDarkRP.png" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%;" alt="" />
</body>
```

Comment: I think that it would be easier to get the song, upload it to your server, and put a play/pause button. If you have the song on your server, the audience doesn't have to wait to the pull from youtube.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example https://jsfiddle.net/mlegg10/576f27a9/2/

```js
(function(){
 var playing = !!('ontouchstart' in window) || !!('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) || !!window.ontouchstart || (!!window.Touch && !!window.Touch.length) || !!window.onmsgesturechange || (window.DocumentTouch && window.document instanceof window.DocumentTouch),
 snd = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0],
 ctrl = document.getElementById('pauseplay');
 playing = !playing;
 ctrl.title = playing? 'Pause' : 'Play';
 if(playing){snd.autoplay = false; ctrl.src = 'http://hamptonsunrise.com/images/pause.png';}
 ctrl.addEventListener('click', function(){
  if(playing){
   snd.pause();
  } else {
   snd.play();
  }
  playing = !playing;
  ctrl.title = playing? 'Pause' : 'Play';
  ctrl.src = playing? 'http://hamptonsunrise.com/images/pause.png' : 'http://hamptonsunrise.com/images/play.png';
 }, false);
})();
```

```css
audio {visibility: hidden; height: 0; width: 0; position: absolute; top: -300px; left: -300px;}
#pauseplay {float: right; width: 48px; height: 48px; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer}
```

```html
<audio controls loop>
<source src="http://hamptonsunrise.com/audio/waves.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="http://hamptonsunrise.com/audio/waves.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<img id="pauseplay" src="http://hamptonsunrise.com/images/play.png" alt="button" title="Play/Pause">
```

live example on [this site](http://hamptonsunrise.com/) I made